# Adding columns and rows into a tablelayoutpanel row dynamically

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

[image]

Hi, I have a windows forms application written in c#. I use tablelayoutpanel that have 5 rows and a column. My question is how could we add red columns and row (they are shown in red color in the picture) into just row 3 in runtime/dynamically ? And how can we reach later to be able to add controls (labels, textboxes, buttons..) into them?
Thanks for advices..

Answer (score 9):

Here an example :

```
private void GenerateControls()
{
    TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
    Button button1 = new Button();
    Button button2 = new Button();
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
    TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
    tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();


    // tableLayoutPanel1
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button2, 1, 0);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button1, 0, 0);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1, 0, 1);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBox1, 1, 1);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 20));
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30F));
    tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(388, 301);
    tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
    tableLayoutPanel1.CellPaint += new TableLayoutCellPaintEventHandler(tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint);

    // button1
    button1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    button1.Name = "button1";
    button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 144);
    button1.TabIndex = 0;
    button1.Text = "button1";
    button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

    // button2
    button2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 3);
    button2.Name = "button2";
    button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 144);
    button2.TabIndex = 1;
    button2.Text = "button2";
    button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

    // pictureBox1
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 153);
    pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
    pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 145);
    pictureBox1.TabIndex = 2;
    pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
    //pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\somepic.jpg");

    // textBox1
    textBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 153);
    textBox1.Multiline = true;
    textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
    textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 145);
    textBox1.TabIndex = 3;

    Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
    tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
}
```

This void will manipulate borders

```
void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == 0)
    {
        var rectangle = e.CellBounds;
        rectangle.Inflate(-1, -1);

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, rectangle, Border3DStyle.Raised, Border3DSide.All); // 3D border
    }
    else if (e.Column == 1 && e.Row == 0)
    {
        var rectangle = e.CellBounds;
        rectangle.Inflate(-1, -1);

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted); // dotted border
    }
}
```